Right-side misalignment of items in a custom environment based on enumerate
I am trying to make a checklist and have made two custom environments for this purpose. However, I am struggeling with the last \item in the environment not spanning the entire line as I would expect it to. Additionally, it seems the last item in the full list (seventh item) has a shorer line than the last item (third) in the subchecklist.

Lastly, as a "side issue" to this, if hyperref is included (uncommented), the first checklist item and the second subhecklist item both have a shorter line as well - this occurs to items above items with a checkmark item.

Anyone have an idea of what may cause this? Both with and without the hyperref package?
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=0.2in,
    right=0.2in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\define@key{checklist@keys}{title}{\def\checklist@title{#1}}%
\define@key{subchecklist@keys}{label}{\def\subchecklist@label{#1}}%

\newcommand{\checkitem}[3][\empty]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}% 
        {%
            \item{#2}\dotfill{#3}%
        }
        {%
            \refstepcounter{\@enumctr} 
            \item[{#1}\,\@nameuse{label\@enumctr}]{#2}\dotfill{#3}
        }
}

\newcommand{\checkpoint}[2][\empty]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}% 
        {%
            \item #2%
        }
        {%
            \refstepcounter{\@enumctr} 
            \item[{#1}\,\@nameuse{label\@enumctr}]#2
        }
}

\newenvironment{subchecklist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{subchecklist@keys}{label=\alph*,#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\subchecklist@label.,leftmargin=*,labelindent=1.2em,topsep=3pt,itemsep=1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=0.25ex]
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}

\newenvironment{checklist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{checklist@keys}{title=,#1}
    \noindent\colorbox{gray!50}{\strut\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\checklist@title}}}}

   \begin{subchecklist}[label=\arabic*]
}{
    \end{subchecklist}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{checklist}[title="Example"]
  \checkitem{First}{Normal.}
  \checkitem{Second}{Indented (with hyperref)}
  \checkitem[\checkmark]{Third}{Normal with checkmark.}
  \checkitem{Fourth}{Normal.}
  \checkitem{Fifth and parent to nested (normal)}{
      \begin{subchecklist}
          \checkitem{First subitem}{Indented (with hyperref)}
          \checkitem[\checkmark]{Second item}{Normal}
          \checkitem{Third item}{Indented (last item)}
      \end{subchecklist}
  }
  \checkitem{Sixth}{Normal}
  \checkitem{Seventh}{Indented (last item)}
\end{checklist}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thank you @Mensch!

Be careful with spaces that may sneak in when you make new commands. To be precise, you'd better add a percent sign (%) at the end of each line which does not end with a macro.
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=0.2in,
    right=0.2in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\define@key{checklist@keys}{title}{\def\checklist@title{#1}}%
\define@key{subchecklist@keys}{label}{\def\subchecklist@label{#1}}%
\newcommand{\checkitem}[3][\empty]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}% 
        {%
            \item{#2}\dotfill{#3}%
        }%
        {%
            \refstepcounter{\@enumctr}%
            \item[{#1}\,\@nameuse{label\@enumctr}]{#2}\dotfill{#3}%
        }%
    \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\checkpoint}[2][\empty]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}% 
        {%
            \item #2%
        }%
        {%
            \refstepcounter{\@enumctr}%
            \item[{#1}\,\@nameuse{label\@enumctr}]#2%
        }%
}

\newenvironment{subchecklist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{subchecklist@keys}{label=\alph*,#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\subchecklist@label.,leftmargin=*,labelindent=1.2em,topsep=3pt,itemsep=1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=0.25ex]
}{\end{enumerate}}

\newenvironment{checklist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{checklist@keys}{title=,#1}
    \noindent\colorbox{gray!50}{\strut\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\checklist@title}}}}
    \begin{subchecklist}[label=\arabic*] 
}{\end{subchecklist}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{checklist}[title=``Example'']
  \checkitem{First}{Normal.}
  \checkitem{Second}{Indented (with hyperref)}
  \checkitem[\checkmark]{Third}{Normal with checkmark.}
  \checkitem{Fourth}{Normal.}
  \checkitem{Fifth and parent to nested (normal)}{
      \begin{subchecklist}
          \checkitem{First subitem}{Indented (with hyperref)}
          \checkitem[\checkmark]{Second item}{Normal}
          \checkitem{Third item}{Indented (last item)}
      \end{subchecklist}
  }
  \checkitem{Sixth}{Normal}
  \checkitem{Seventh}{Indented (last item)}
\end{checklist}
\end{document}


Thank you! This did indeed solve the problem. I'll be adopting this practice from now on.
